# React getting an object from localStorage, can't set it with react useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have the following code for App.js. The useEffect hook will run at startup of the App, and I expect it to retrieve an object from localStorage and then set it to the useState user variable.

CONSOLE.LOG OUTPUT:

> JSON user {"name":"tester","username":"test username","password":"testpassword","token":"test token"}

> parsed user {name: 'tester', username: 'test username', password: 'testpassword', token: 'test token'}

> current logged in user:  null

```js
const App = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // CHECK IF THERE IS A LOGGED IN USER FROM PREVIOUS SESSIONS
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem("loggedInUser");
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      console.log("JSON user", loggedUserJSON);
      const parsedUser = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON);
      console.log("parsed user", parsedUser);
      setUser(parsedUser);
    }
    console.log("current logged in user: ", user);
  }, []);
```

And the following is the event handler for my login component:

```js
  const login = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const user = await UserService.login({
        username: username,
        password: password,
      });
      window.localStorage.setItem("loggedInUser", JSON.stringify(user));
      history.push("/home");
    } catch (exception) {
      console.log(exception);
    }
  };
```

Now I can see that the object goes into the browser's local storage correctly, and I can even properly parse it based on my console.log output. But somehow

```
setUser(parsedUser);
```

doesn't work. It gives the default value of null. What makes the setUser to fail?

Comment: there is a slight misunderstanding how the first code snippet works `setUser(parsedUser);` then in the same function logging out `user` won't work because the state hasn't actually been updated yet. you need to wait for the component to render again before trying to access the `user` state. if you just move `console.log("current logged in user: ", user);` to outside of the `useEffect` into the component body, it should fire twice and first it will log `null` then on render it will fire and should log your user

Answer (score 2):

`setUser` useState function will not instantly assign the value to user like `user = parsedUser` it is working different, it will only set your value in it next render,

check the answer in this link.

[useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Solution

Either you can check the value on its next render, or you can check the change in one another useEffect

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // CHECK IF THERE IS A LOGGED IN USER FROM PREVIOUS SESSIONS
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem("loggedInUser");
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      console.log("JSON user", loggedUserJSON);
      const parsedUser = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON);
      console.log("parsed user", parsedUser);
      setUser(parsedUser);
    }
    console.log("current logged in user: ", user); // this will only print null because `setUser(parsedUser)` is not yet reflected 
  }, []);
console.log("current logged in user on every render: ", user);  // this will console the value on its second render, becase second render happens when ` setUser(parsedUser);` completed
}
```

Another method to check the change is use one another `useEffect`

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // CHECK IF THERE IS A LOGGED IN USER FROM PREVIOUS SESSIONS
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem("loggedInUser");
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      console.log("JSON user", loggedUserJSON);
      const parsedUser = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON);
      console.log("parsed user", parsedUser);
      setUser(parsedUser);
    }
    console.log("current logged in user: ", user); // this will only 
   print null becase `setUser(parsedUser)` is not yet reflected 
  }, []);
  useEffect(()=> {
     console.log("current logged in user on every render: ", user);  // this will console the value every time user value changes intially it will be null and on second time it will show your data
  },[user])
}
```